# Singleton not work across mutiple file Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, singleton

I try to create a singleton instance of Event Emitter as following

In the file mediator.js

```
const {EventEmitter} = require('events')

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.test = Math.random()
    }
}

class Singleton {
    getInstance() {
        console.log(Singleton.instance)
        if (!Singleton.instance) {
            Singleton.instance = new MyEmitter()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
}


module.exports = Singleton
```

In file test_mediator_1.js, I create an instances

```
const MyEmitter = require('./mediator')
const mediator = new MyEmitter().getInstance()
console.log(mediator)
```

I got the an instances.

```
MyEmitter {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  test: 0.255542039674032,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Howere, in the test_mediator_2.js:

```
const MyEmitter = require('./mediator')
const mediator = new MyEmitter().getInstance()
console.log(mediator)
```

I got a different instance  (test property in 2 instance are different)

```
MyEmitter {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  test: 0.9233626983577679,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

How can I get the singleton instance across multiple file ???

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your examples are totally fine and your singleton is working properly. How do you require these test_mediator_1.js and  these test_mediator_2.js?

Comment: The 2 instances in 2 file test_mediator_1.js and test_mediator_2.js is not the same. So when i listen on event at file test_mediator_1: 
```
media.on('test', (data) => console.log(data))
```

And in file mediator_2.js, I emit an event: 
```
mediator.emit('test', 'hello')
```
The event is not triggered in file mediator_1.js. However when I emit an events at file mediator_1.js, I still reveived the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the way you are creating the singleton. I tried this and it is working fine as well. It gives me the same instance when I require two files.

ALso, regarding emitting event, you need to make sure that emitting of events needs to happen after you register your listener. If you run your file which has emit part first, the data will be emitted and since there is no listener, it will be lost. I guess that is what is happening in your case. Make sure the sequence is correct.

Comment: Do you get the same value of test property in 2 objects??

Comment: yes..same value. how are you requiring your two files?

Comment: Thank you, I found the mistake that I run 2 files test_mediator_1.js and test_mediator_2.js as 2 separate programs. And I need to run listener before emit.